# How does Object this concept link itself to other concepts like glGenBuffers , glBindBuffer , glBufferData . etc?

Tags: opengl, graphics, rendering

e.g. Vertex Buffer Object . However , I know what it is , and it is something used to store datas representing some specific places in a certain space , which would be called by GL later to draw specific images , hence when drawing , GL would extract datas from VBO , and the word 'buffer' stands for 'vessel' , storing various things from vertex to others , and I know there were firstly datas in CPU , then datas passed to GPU for quick calling . I know all these things , but what exactly does Object this word mean ? How does Object this concept link itself to other concepts like glGenBuffers , glBindBuffer , glBufferData . etc ? What did the Object this class do when GPU had the need to receive datas from CPU?
I had referred to https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Object but its description looks weird . Doesn't glBindBuffer generate object itself ? Why does the author call it 'state' , hinting there was already object when glGenBuffer ?
Thx for your answers

Comment: `glGenBuffer` does not generate any object. `glGenBuffer` just generates (object) IDs, that can be used to to create objects.

Comment: "*Doesn't glBindBuffer generate object itself ?*" That is literally what the cited page says: "For most object types, the object will only contain its default state when it is first bound to the context;"

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Oops I get it !  ''The state of a buffer object immediately after it is first bound is an unmapped zero-sized memory buffer with GL_READ_WRITE access and GL_STATIC_DRAW usage.''(https://docs.gl/gl4/glBindBuffer) It is really object itself , but not only object , as object is always something carrying states

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.